# How to have Qt run asynchroneously for interactive use like Matplotlib's ion mode?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside2

I want to be able to launch a Qt interface from the python interpreter, with the command line returning immediately, so that I can continue using python while being able to use the interface. Basically I would like to be able to interact with the GUI from the interpreter like one can with matplotlib's `ion` interactive mode, or in a jupyter notebook, or in Matlab.

I tried naively to put the execution of the application in a thread:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsRectItem, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QMainWindow

class Rect(QGraphicsRectItem):
  def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    print("foo")

app = QApplication([])

class AppThread(QThread):
  def run(self):
    app.exec()
    print('bar')


window = QMainWindow()
window.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 400)
view = QGraphicsView()
scene = QGraphicsScene()
rect = Rect(0, 0, 150, 150)
scene.addItem(rect)
view.setScene(scene)
window.setCentralWidget(view)
window.show()

thread = AppThread()
thread.start()
```

...but that does not work because the GUI that is produced is frozen and thus unusable.

One of matplotlib's backend is `Qt5Agg` and I thought naively that this would mean I could use PyQt5 or PySide2 to achieve a similar effect.

Is it indeed possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to use a thread or the complement of another library, you just have to execute the commands but you should not call the exec_() method of QApplication since it uses the python interactive console eventloop.

```
$ python
Python 3.8.2 (default, Feb 26 2020, 22:21:03) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20200130] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information
>>> from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsRectItem, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QMainWindow
>>> class Rect(QGraphicsRectItem):
...   def mousePressEvent(self, event):
...     print("foo")
... 
>>> app = QApplication([])
>>> window = QMainWindow()
>>> window.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 400)
>>> view = QGraphicsView()
>>> scene = QGraphicsScene()
>>> rect = Rect(0, 0, 150, 150)
>>> scene.addItem(rect)
>>> view.setScene(scene)
>>> window.setCentralWidget(view)
>>> window.show()
```

**IPython**

As the [IPython docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/eventloops.html) points out, `%gui backend` must be used to enable the GUI event loops. In the case of PyQt5/PySide2, `%gui qt5` must be used at the beginning.

```
$ ipython
Python 3.8.2 (default, Feb 26 2020, 22:21:03) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.13.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: %gui qt5                                                                                                                                                                                

In [2]: from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsRectItem, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QMainWindow                                                                                 

In [3]: class Rect(QGraphicsRectItem): 
   ...:   def mousePressEvent(self, event): 
   ...:     print("foo") 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [4]: app = QApplication([])                                                                                                                                                                  

In [5]: window = QMainWindow()                                                                                                                                                                  

In [6]: window.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 400)                                                                                                                                                  

In [7]: view = QGraphicsView()                                                                                                                                                                  

In [8]: scene = QGraphicsScene()                                                                                                                                                                

In [9]: rect = Rect(0, 0, 150, 150)                                                                                                                                                             

In [10]: scene.addItem(rect)                                                                                                                                                                    

In [11]: view.setScene(scene)                                                                                                                                                                   

In [12]: window.setCentralWidget(view)                                                                                                                                                          

In [13]: window.show()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. I tested on Windows and on Linux -- on both platforms the GUI is still frozen.

Comment: @user209974 How strange, how did you open the interactive python console? I use Linux and just type python in the console and press ENTER, then I write the commands I show in my answer (`app.exec()` should not be used)

Comment: I used ipython -- could that make a difference?

Comment: Oh yes it does -- just tried in a plain python interpreter and it works

Comment: Any idea how to make it work in ipython? Or is that an entirely different topic?